# Using one random variable multiple times in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, lazy-evaluation

It'd like to make a random sequence of opening braces and a matching sequence of closing braces. Here's my (partial) code:

```
shuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
ps xs ys = map snd . sort $ zip xs ys

opens  = "[{("
closes = "]})"

parens = do
ord <- shuffle [0..length opens]
  let os  = ps ord opens
      cs  = reverse $ ps ord closes
```

It doesn't work since it generates a new `ord` for each shuffle. How do I make it remember the `ord` and use it for both shuffles?

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer your question if your code was less partial (gives us something that at least is correct syntax.) Right now it is hard to see exactly what your issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't shuffle them separately.

Shuffle the `zip`ped sequence, and `unzip` when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Oleg's [*Provably* perfect shuffle algorithms](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/perfect-shuffle.txt) or the [System.Random.Shuffle](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random-shuffle/latest/doc/html/System-Random-Shuffle.html) implementation?

Upon rereading your (very incomplete) code, it appears that it *could* be correct, making some assumptions about the surrounding code.  Please show more so we can determine what might be wrong.

As an aside, using `` map fst . sortBy (comparing `on` fst) . zip xs `` or `map fst . sortWith fst . zip xs` would more clearly express that your intent is to order one list by another.